Can't fix error 405 in next.js with stripe
I can't figure out what is causing 405 error when trying to fetch an endpoint in next.js
Here is my fetch function:
    React.useEffect(() => {
    // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
    fetch("/api/create-payment-intent", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ items: [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }] }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
  }, []);

And here is the endpoint:
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const calculateOrderAmount = (items) => {
  return 1400;
};

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { items } = req.body;

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "eur",
    automatic_payment_methods: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  });

  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });

};


HTTP 405 indicates the method you're using isn't allowed.  Your fetch code is trying to use the POST method, but your server is rejecting a POST request to the URL in question.  It's likely the issue is in code you haven't shared, which defines the endpoint (it's probably the code wrapping the endpoint code you did share).  Can you edit your question and share more of your server-side code, especially where you're defining paths and methods?
